# How to show error message with tailwindcss condtionally?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to show error message with react-hook-form and tailwind css conditionally.

```
export const FieldWrapper: FunctionComponent<FieldWrapperProps> = (props: FieldWrapperProps) => {
  const { children, label, errorMessage, className } = props;

  return (
    <div
      className={clsx('mt-6 flex flex-col justify-center tracking-wide align-middle', className)}
    >
      <label htmlFor={label} className="block text-gray-light text-base  font-bold mb-2 peer">
        {label}
      </label>
      {children}
      {errorMessage && <p className="text-sm text-red-500 ">{errorMessage}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am reusing this component, but when there is an error message it pushes down the component itself to show error message and breaks the layout.

How do i make it so, it does not push the component down?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using `justify-start` instead of `justify-center`